# Objective-C JSON Boolean

Tags: objective-c, json

I have parsed a json object that has the following structure:

```
{
    data = "<null>";
    "error_type" = "INPUT_ERROR";
    msg = "Missing field parameter";
    success = 0;
}
```

I'm trying to do a compariosn to see whether success is true or false, however it dosnt work and gives me a warning saying you can't compare a pointer as a integer. I've also tried NO and YES.

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe `success` is likely being cast to a NSNumber. Try `[success boolValue]`.

Comment: Should mention I'm assuming you're using a library such as TouchJSON.

Comment: @Ian Livingstone: Make sure to accept the answer! (click the checkbox below the vote count)

Comment: I will; has a ten minute timer makes me sad :(